# Information about time-to-digital converters (TDCs)

Tags: sensor

I'm going to measure short times (max 150 microseconds). To do this I will use time-to-digital converters (TDCs). They don't seem to be very common and it's hard to find information about them on internet. I wonder if someone here can answer my questions.

1. Which companies make these things? So far I've only found [Acam](http://www.acam.de). Is there more manufacturers?
2. They are connected with SPI. Can I connect six of them to a single MCU? The problem is that all six can sometimes send the measurement at the same time. What happens then?
3. Is there an alternative which would do the same? A resolution needed is 50 nanoseconds.

Comment: The reason they're uncommon is because almost every microprocessor on the market can do exactly what that IC does using it's internal timer modules. If you have a MCU, why do you need a separate timer?

Comment: I've considered using microcontroller to measure the time but resolution of 50 nanoseconds is very hard to achieve with AVR for example. A common maximum clock rate for them is 20 MHz. So I would have one clock cycle for 50 nanoseconds. 32 MHz of some models isn't much better.

Comment: Don't most AVRs have timers that include timer / capture that can run at 20MHz? That should still work unless you have the pulses arriving arriving quickly, like a few 50nS pulses in a row. FWIW I was looking for some 100ps range stuff a year or so back and Acam was all I found as well.

Comment: If you only need time-resolution of 50 ns, a hardware capture-compare module at 20 Mhz would probably work fine (it's a hardware module, remember!). If you need better time resolution, look into ARM MCUs (and some of the PICs, I think)- they can go 70+ Mhz.

Comment: An interrupt driven AVR on a 20MHz clock will achieve this

Comment: Can it? I asked at the AVRfreaks and they promised only 200 nanosecond resolution.

Comment: At least ATtiny45 has a PLL driven 64MHz (15'ish ns) peripheral clock. Maybe that is of better use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the first I have heard of your "time to digital converter" thingies.  That is probably because I've never tried to look for a stand-alone part like this before, which is because just about all microcontrollers have this capability built in.

Many many micros have the capability to capture the value of a free-running timer on a edge of a digital input.  That seems to be what you want.  You need 50 ns resolution, so the timer needs to increment at 20 MHz rate at minimum.  There are plenty of micros that can do that.  Some of the dsPIC, for example, can run at 40 MHz instruction rate, which is also the rate the timer can be incremented at.  That would give you twice the resolution you need.

It is unclear if you want to measure the width of a pulse or the time between two separate events.  It also matters what the minimum possible time between the start and end capture is.  Depending on the answer, you can do this with a single capture module or you may need two for each pulse.  If the minimum time is long enough, then the firmware can grab the capture value from the first event and reconfigure the capture hardware for the second event.  If the time is too short, you need separate capture hardware for each edge, perferably running from the same timer.

Take a look at the "Input Capture" module of dsPICs.  One or two of these should do what you want.  You may not be able to handle all 6 signals in a single micro, but micros are cheap, so use one for each signal if you have to.  That also makes communicating the result back to some central location easier since you can implement any protocol you want.

For more specific recommendations we need to know what the minimum time between the edges are, how/if the 6 signals need to be synchronized, do they have a commmon start time, etc?

Comment: Using a microcpntroller to do this would be great. I only know that this isn't possible with AVR.

Comment: @Kestis: It probably is possible with AVRs, although I am not familiar with the details of that line.  It is definitely possible with some of the dsPICs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to connect multiple TDC on the SPI, you need to consider two things:

1. The presence of a CS
2. The max frequency of your SPI clock (the faster the better to be able to query all the devices before your next round of measurement).

Another example not listed above is the [TDC7200](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tdc7200.pdf), which has CS and a SPI clock frequency up to 20MHz and [TDC7201](http://www.ti.com/product/TDC7201), which is a dual TDC and has SPI clock up to 25MHz.